# Get children of multiple roots expected json result

Tags: json, rest, jsonresult

I tried to find good sorces for finding out what is the right way of doing it but i couldnt find anything realy...

So the problem is that if i want to get children of multiple roots i would call that via the following REST route.

`GET /children?roots=2,4`

The result could now have two possiblities

1.

```
[
    {
        root: 2,
        children: [1, 2]
    },
    {
        root: 4,
        children: [3, 4]
    }
]
```

2. 

```
[
    {
        child : 1
        root : 2
    },
    {
        child : 2
        root : 2
    },
    {
        child : 3
        root : 4
    },
    {
        child : 4
        root : 4
    }
]
```

Which one would be the expected result and why? I Personally would go for the first aproch.

Comment: the answer will depends on what you'll want to do with the data

Comment: I would argue that this should not matter right? Because its the same data just differently presented.

Comment: I don't think your question is suited for SO. You are not facing any issue, your question is just opinion based which need a lot more context to be able to catch the requirements. I'd suggest you to start the way you feel it's appropriate. If you split your code properly, you'll still be able to refactor your code. Come back here to submit any actual problem you may encounter later.

Comment: i think in general the first solution should be more it.